# Mips do arithmetic operation before compilation

Tags: mips, precompile, mars-simulator

In C I could do this:

`#define WIDTH 200
 #define HEIGHT 200
 #define SIZE WIDTH*HEIGHT`

If I do that, the generated code doesn't have the unnecessary multiplication of WIDTH*HEIGHT, since the precompiler calculates it beforehand and replaces SIZE with $40000$. Is there a way to do the same in mips (more specifically with the Mars simulator if it matters?)? i.e I have

`.eqv WIDTH 200
 .eqv HEIGHT 200`

And I don't want to waste a few cycles doing mult manually, if there is a way to process that in the precompiler.

Comment: MARS is quite limited when it comes to its expression evaluation. It will handle things like `foo+1` where `foo` is a label. But it doesn't handle things like `addi $a0, $0, 1+2`. And as far as I can tell, its parser doesn't even recognize `*` as a valid token.

Comment: I just spent a few minutes diving around in its guts at github.  As @Michael said, this is a very limited emulator.  If you were to use an actual MIPS assembler, you could expect this sort of support, but not through this.